# neo4j Multiple optional paths - cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm tracking if a user has liked and or voted on a object in a list of objects others posted.. I can get  either likes and votes, but not both.  (A person can both like and vote on an object and these options are not mutually exclusive).

To simply this problem let me describe it in relational terms (left joins used - object is ALWAYS returned, liker and voter data is only returned if a record of that type exists)

```
[object]+ -> liker
        + -> voter
```

What I'd like to return is:

```
objectID likerID  voterID
2343     null     88
2345     11       null
2382     44       1256
2400     null     null
```

Yet every which way I've sliced I cannot get it to come out like that .  Either row 2400 is skipped (I've tried every combination of where), or values are even shifted from likerID to the voterID column (bug?).

Here is a sample of the cypher:

```
    start objects=node(158) 
match contestant-[:POSTED]->object_node-[:POSTED_OBJECT]->objects<-[?:POSTED_OBJECT]-object_node_a<-[?:LIKES]-liker
    , objects<-[?:POSTED_OBJECT]-object_node_b<-[?:VOTES]-voter
    return id(object, id(liker), id(voter)
```

It doesn't work even if I try where id(object_node_a) = id(object_node_b)...

If I just try to get a liker it works.. same with voter.. but when I try to do both.. bombs..

I've tried using where , etc but ultimately I never get the full list of objects - it either trims down the list based upon matches, or gives me the Cartesian product which distinct does not resolve.

SQL EXAMPLE: LEFT JOIN

I'm a sql guy so let me explain it this way - I have a objects table on the left, and I want to left join it to a liker table and a voter table, and return both the liker id and voter id on a single row along with the object data.  All the object records will be returned regardless if there is a voter or liker record.

```
[object]+ -> liker
        + -> voter
```

IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE?

Is it possible to do this via cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I haven't misunderstood. To get

```
objectID likerID  voterID
2343     null     88
2345     11       null
2382     44       1256
2400     null     null
```

i.e. all objects and the ID of those that liked it and voted for it, this query should do it-

```
start o=<lookup for objects>
match ul-[like?:LIKED]->o, uv-[vote?:VOTED]->o 
return o,ID(ul),ID(uv)
```

This will return objects that no votes and likes, both votes and likes and either one. Note that if you have multiple users voting for the same object as is likely, then your object row will repeat for each user. You might want to do something like

```
start o=<lookup for objects>
match ul-[like?:LIKED]->o, uv-[vote?:VOTED]->o 
return o,collect(ID(ul)),collect(ID(uv))
```

to still get a row per object but a collection of user IDS for votes and likes.

To include the person that posted the object as well:

```
start o=node(4,5,6,7) 
match ul-[like?:LIKED]->o, uv-[vote?:VOTED]->o, c-[:POSTED_OBJECT]->o 
return o,ID(ul),ID(uv),ID(c)
```

I created a tiny sample to play with: http://console.neo4j.org/r/in8g4w

Comment: Definitely cleaner, but I need to retrieve contestant data also. I can get results with two matches, but when I try a third on no dice.. Something more like this:

start o=<lookup for objects>
match ul<-[like?:LIKES]-o, 
uv<-[vote?:VOTES]-o,
contestant<-[postedobj?:POSTED_OBJECT]-o
return o,ID(ul),ID(uv), ID(contestant)    - I am filtering out other users - and the current user is only allowed one vote and one like.. So there won't be multiple rows, just a single row per object

Comment: Edited my answer above, does that help?

Comment: Yea.. much better!  It got me on the right path I think.. one further question .. how does one deal with collections? Does that take place outside of Neo/Cypher?  I'm using Ruby on Rails - would I just simply take those collections and parse them out in my code? or are the collections for Cypher use only?  BTW Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. I use Java so when I have Cypher queries that return collections of Nodes or properties, I actually get a Collection object and iterate through it for processing in my code. Not sure what the equivalent is in Ruby. I guess you could ask another question specifically for the Ruby client.

Comment: Ok.. A hash will work in ROR I believe.. This is pretty cool because I like the capabilities of Cypher = mainly less coding and more sql like and great for rapid app development - but need the capability to work with "children" of an object without having to query the database a second time. Seems ideal for handling comments on posts etc.. Very nice!  Cypher may be slower, but hey, first to market is important - refactoring and performance tuning can come later.. :-)